# Notation for limits

Tags: limits

In my notes, I have the following theorem on 'the convergence of the random walk to the Wiener process', written as follows:

Let $X_1,X_2,...$ be a sequence of independent and identically distributed random variables with common distribution given by $P(X_i=1)=P(X_i=-1)=\frac{1}{2}$ for all $i$. For $t>0$, define the processes
$$Y_h(t)=\sqrt{h}\sum_{i=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{t}{h}\right\rfloor}X_i$$
where $\lfloor-\rfloor$ denotes the floor function. Then there exists a Wiener process $Y(t)$ such that
$$Y(t):= \lim_{h\rightarrow0,h>0}Y_h(t)$$

Question:
Is $\lim_{h\rightarrow0,h>0}Y_h(t)$ the same as saying $\lim_{h\rightarrow0^+}Y_h(t)$? If so, is it only in this case, or in all cases. If not, why?

Comment: Offhand, I'd _expect_ both notations to have the same meaning (to the extent I'd feel misled if the meanings were not identical), but this is a question best asked of your professor.

Comment: Because of the square root, the only meaningful limit is indeed the limit $\lim_{x\to 0^+}$.